# Does office js dialog api supports in IOS Outlook app

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Does office js dialog api (Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync) supports in IOS Outlook app ?

according to the [outlook-api-requirement-sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets#outlook-client-support)  minimum API requirement sets are *1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5* and
[dialog-api-in-office-add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) doc also doesn't have  any note about restriction

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://myDomain/myDialog.html', {
    height: 30,
    width: 20,
    displayInIframe: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is part of [Outlook Req Set 1.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.4/outlook-requirement-set-1.4), so it should be supported in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

We do support Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync in iOS. As @Rick Kirkham  mentioned, [Outlook Req Set 1.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.4/outlook-requirement-set-1.4) contains the related documentation.